# :thingo v 'thingo' with values in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I have a hash of values from a database query:

```
a1 = {:a => 1, :b => 2 }
```

And another hash of values for a third party library:

```
b1 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }
```

I'd like to see if `a1` has `'a'` which I like to consider the equivalent of `:a`.  How is that done?  So I can check if there are any missing keys from `b1` in `a1`.

What I want is to treat the key `'a'` as the same as the key `:a`.

Comment: Rails?  Hard to tell, I'm in RhoMobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an array of (string) keys from `b1` that are not present (as symbol keys) in `a1`:

```
b1.keys - a1.keys.map { |key| key.to_s }
```

You can then do:

```
missing = b1.keys - a1.keys.map { |key| key.to_s }
missing.each do |key|
    a1[key.to_sym] = b1[key]
end
```

That's assuming `b1` always has only string keys, you're only worried about `a1` missing key/value pairs from `b1`, and your goal is to insert the missing pairs into `a1` (with symbol keys), all of which sound true from your question.  If any of those assumptions are false, this should at least get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_sym`

```
a.has_key?('a'.to_sym)
```

Comment: Note that this may have unexpected behavior if you happen to have `{:a => 1, "a" => 2}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options given a Hash `h`:

- You can convert all keys to strings:

  ```
  Hash[h.map { |k, v| [k.to_s, v] }]
  ```
- You can convert all keys to symbols:

  ```
  Hash[h.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }]
  ```
- You can use [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), which comes from [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) (which comes with Rails for free):

  ```
  HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(h)
  ```